# Scrapy. Unexpected symbols in LinkExtractor

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am studying Scrapy library and trying to make a little crawler.

Here's the crawler's rules:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="wrapper"]/div[last()]/a[@class="pagenav"][last()]')),
    # Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//span[@class="update_title"]/a'), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

But I get this error message:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://web/category.php?id=4&> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://web/%0D%0Acategory.php?id=4&page=2&s=d> (referer: http://web/category.php?id=4&)
DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 http://web/%0D%0Acategory.php?id=4&page=2&s=d>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Here's how html look like:

```
<a class="pagenav" href=" category.php?id=4&page=8&s=d& ">8</a>
|
<a class="pagenav" href=" category.php?id=4&page=9&s=d& ">9</a>
|
<a class="pagenav" href=" category.php?id=4&page=10&s=d& ">10</a>
|         
<a class="pagenav" href=" category.php?id=4&page=2&s=d& ">Next ></a>
```

Can someone explain where's this %0D%0A come from?
Kind regards, Maxim.

**UPD**:
I made a simple function

```
def process_value(value):
    value = value.strip()
    print value
    return value
```

and changed rules to

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="wrapper"]/div[last()]/a[@class="pagenav"][last()]', process_value=process_value)),
    # Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//span[@class="update_title"]/a'), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

print command prints this:

```
Crawled (200) <GET http://web/category.php?id=4&>(referer: None)
http://web/
category.php?id=4&page=2&s=d&
Crawled (404) <GET http://web/%0D%0Acategory.php?%0D=&id=4&page=2&s=d>(referer: http://web/category.php?id=4&)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are extracting the `href` tag ?

Comment: As per my guess you need to `strip` the relative url first and then make a request. Stripping will remove the `carriage return-%0D` and `line feed-%0A` characters.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason .strip() won't work :(

Comment: Well, try to perform that before strip `url=urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')`. Sorry for the dirty response: I'm out of my laptop.

Comment: There are actually open issue and PRs on this in scrapy: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/838, https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1021, https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%0D` and `%0A` are `CR` and `LF` characters in HTML-encoding.

Author of the website which you parse put the characters into HTML document. I think, occasionally, because they aren't visible in IDE or browser.

Explanation what the invisible characters mean:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

And more about the encoding http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

I suggest you to strip all the links which need to fetch in the way like that:

```
href = href.strip()
```

Comment: Seems like .strip() can't handle with this well-formed HTML code :D